# How can I select the minimummonths value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In SQL I would do this:

```
SELECT minimummonths WHERE name = "gold"
```

I want to do the same in Ruby on Rails and have the following in the new section of my orders controller:

```
@plan = params[:plan]

@Payplanrow = Payplan.where(:name => @plan).minimummonths
```

I then try to display `@payplanrow` in my page using `<%=@Payplanrow %>` but it doesnt work. I get the error:

```
undefined method `minimummonths' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe30f870ec0>
```

I want to print the `minimummonths` value for the plan selected. There will only ever be one row of data corresponding to the `@plan` value.

I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails so I'm just trying to get a pointer in the right direction. I looked everywhere but there doesn't seem to be an example of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Payplan.where(:name => @plan)` is returning an array of `Payplan` objects. Assuming you are using Rails 3, you can read more about it in "[Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)".

But, if you are certain that your query is returning only one record you could do:

```
@Payplanrow = Payplan.where(:name => @plan).first.try(:minimummonths)
```

The Rails way is to have a scope in your model:

```
class Payplan < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :by_name, lambda {|name|
     {:conditions => {:name => name}}
  }

end

#controller 
@Payplanrow = Payplan.by_name(@plan).first.try(:minimummonths)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not really optimal, you can do:

```
@Payplanrow = Payplan.where(:name => @plan).first.minimummonths
```

Comment: .first should come before .minimummonths :)

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
Payplan.where(:name => @plan).first.minimummonths
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pluck`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) to get only the `minimummonths` value :

```
minimummonths = Payplan.where(:name => @plan).pluck(:minimummonths).first
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `where then first`, it's better to use `find` when you are expecting a `single record`.

```
 @Payplanrow = Payplan.find_by_name(@plan).try(:minimummonths)
```